# Invoking "Run" button of Eclipse via code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-api

I have created a sample eclipse plugin development with a button.

```
@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    
    Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("button");        
    button.addSelectionListener((SelectionListener) new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to initiate eclipse run for a other java file(any other java class) when this button is clicked. Is there any way to programmatically control the run button of the eclipse?

Comment: See [Launching a Program](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_launch.htm&cp%3D2_0_17_0) in the Eclipse help - this is a complex API.

Comment: [This article](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html) should also be useful - the example talks about launching Tomcat but most of the article applies to launching other things.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. As you said , that example explains about launching Tomcat. I am facing issue because IpluginDescriptor is deprecated. It would be nice if you could share any other handy examples if there are any?

Comment: I don't see any mention of IPluginDescriptor in those links, note that it doesn't exist at all in current Eclipse versions. I don't have any examples.

Comment: Ok. FYI : IPluginDescriptor is used in the example source code in that article. Anyway Thanks @greg-449. Keep supporting and posting your answers for various questions. Cheers! Looking for any other answers for this post from others!